# Using DDrescue to Backup Local Disk on Corrupted vBox VDI

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, unix, ddrescue

After some crafty, -guessing-, I finally got this command to create a local .img of a remote disk (vbox) that is failing.

It work, -slowly-, but it works:

```
ssh root@example  ddrescue -d /dev/sda1 - | pv | cat > /home/user/path/to/tester1.img | cat > /home/user/path/to/tester1.logfile
```

My question is about the "| cat > /home/user/path/to/tester1.logfile " portion of the command...

Clearly this will take hours and put strain on the disk, however I don't want to wait the entire time then discover that there isn't a logfile that I can check.

Can someone with better unix skills than me, verify logfile  portion of my command or provide a better solution?

thx

**Solution:**
Big thanks (and apologies) to @davidgo

I eventually used this to get save my data from a failing .vdi disk:

```
#ddrescue -d /dev/sda /media/sf_shared_folder/tester1.iso /media/sf_shared_foldertester-dd.log
```

with his original solution, I didn't see the change in direction of ssh from "localhost to remote", "remote to local", which caused some confusion.. Additionally, when I tried the `sshfs -C user@targetmachine:/home/user/path/to /m2` I ended up with a ssh error "connection reset by peer".

Comment: I very much doubt that command is doing what you are attempting.  Have you had a look at /home/user/path/to/tester1.img ?  I expect you will find it contains only the output of the ddrescue command, not the image.  IF THIS IS THE CASE, AND IF THE DISK IS DYING, YOU SHOULD STOP THIS COMMAND TO REDUCE RISK OF FURTHER DAMAGE TO THE DISK.   (I'm going to think on a solution and I'll post an answer if I do)

Comment: ok... I am not running it now, for the aforementioned reason. Can you recommend a better solution?

Comment: I've posted an initial answer.   Question though,  Is the disk actually damaged?  If not, there are much easier ways to do this without using ddrescue.   Also, is /dev/sda1 mounted - if so, you should expect corruption in the final image - it is very much less then ideal to do a block copy on an active mounted device.

Comment: GNU `ddrescue` needs the output file and the mapfile to be seekable. Trying to redirect any of them to a pipe is futile. Locally you redirect *something* to `tester1.img` and further piping makes no sense. Your `ddrescue` probably writes the image to a regular file named `-` (i.e. `./-`). And you told it not to use a mapfile at all.

Comment: [You can answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) but let the answer be an answer, *not a part of the question*. I can see you had posted an answer, then deleted; I believe you can edit it and undelete. Question = problem; answer = solution. Don't mix them.

Comment: ok will do.. one sec

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt that command is doing what you are attempting.  Have you had a look at /home/user/path/to/tester1.img ?  I expect you will find it contains only the output of the ddrescue command, not the image.

If its an option, I would use SSHFS on "example" (or NFS or something else) to expose /home/user/path/to on the local filesystem across the network and then use ddrescue with its regular invocation, ie, or example

SSHFS uses "FUSE" to remotely expose a remote filesystem on a local machine.   You can likely use commands on "example" like

```
  mkdir /m2 
  sshfs -C user@targetmachine:/home/user/path/to /m2
  ddrescue -d /dev/sda1 /m2/tester1.iso /m2/tester-dd.log
```

The "-C" in the SSHFS command above enables compression via SSH, this assumes that the network is a constraint rather then CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, not quite getting this work... should there be a space between 
"user@targetmachine:/home/user/path/to" and "/m2" in the 2nd line above?
No space I get "fuse: bad mount point `ddrescue': No such file or directory"

Comment: With a space I get  "fuse: bad mount point `/m2': No such file or directory
"

Comment: It should have a space. Did you issue the "mkdir /m2" command to make the path first?  (There is nothing special about /m2 - you can use any empty directory.)

Comment: I can mount the remote directory with "sshfs -C root@tester1:/ /home/user/path/to/m2", but I can't get ddresucue running

Comment: Being a little more explicit might help, have never used this before..

Comment: When I run "$ddrescue -d /dev/sda1 /Im2/tester1.img /m2/tester-dd.log" I get "ddrescue: Can't open input file: Permission denied"

Comment: You are being a bit unfair.  You are attempting fairly advanced and risky stuff, but are not properly reading error messages, providing meaningful error messages, answering my questions yet you are asking me to be more explicit (on things I cant really be more explicit about, not knowing the errors or your knowledge gaps).  Maybe if you advise the ddrescue error/failure message you are getting someone will help.   Im not getting paid and its past my bedtime.

Comment: Did you run the command as root?  (The error clearly states the problem - sda1 was unreadable.).  If you are not root  type "sudo /bin/bash" to become root.  Be aware you are well into dangerous territory and are not qualified to do what you are attempting.  Dont hold me responsible if things go bad.

Comment: Well yes, if you dont understand the ddrescue command, and dont follow my instructions and specify a non-existent file name for the third parameter, that will happen.   Really  you should not be attempting this kind of work.  You are a danger to yourself, and probably dont know enough to know the risk in what you are doing.  If this is anything more then playing around You really need to get an expert to do this.

Comment: I dont think my instructions were wrong.  I think you have not understood them, and fear you are backing up the wrong disk.  I hope im wrong.  (I do note that I have done a fair bit of this kind of work....)

Comment: I rejected your edit.  It goes against my intent and is definately wrong.  You dont run the code block "as a regular user. " You run it as root.  You  also run it FROM THE SYSTEM WITH THE FAILING DISK as indicated.

Comment: my apologies... I missed this part of your original post, hence the confusion " I would use SSHFS on "example" (or NFS or something else)"

Comment: Amateur end-around... from the remote machine  (vbox)  I ran '#ddrescue -d /dev/sda1 /media/sf_VBShared/tester1.iso /media/sf_VBShared/tester-dd.log'   same end goal achieved

Comment: not meaning to "kick a dead horse", be we were both wrong.. In your answer you wrote "tester1.iso"... ddrescue only produces .img files. Sorry for snapping at you, last week was a toughie.

Comment: @yupthatguy In Linux `.iso` or `.img` is just a part of the name. The file can be named `whatever` and it doesn't change *anything*.

Comment: fair enough, you guys know more than me... it's just that in vbox, I can mount an iso file directly, whereas and img has to be converted, then mounted.  As ddrescue only produces .img output... I thought it might be confusing to use .iso in the file name... In any case, this problem is solved... onto the next thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Solution**
process to backup & restore a corrupt (local) vdi

1.) in vbox manager add an bootable iso disk to the corrupt vdi and boot the vdi into it (i.e. ubuntu liveCD)
2.) open the disks utility and ensure that targeted disk is not mounted (i.e. /dev/ )

3.) install vbox guest additions onto the the booted iso to gain access to shared folders (assuming shared folders already exists) and via terminal change into the shared folder

4.) install gddrescue onto the booted iso, via terminal (inside shared folder), run:

```
$sudo su
# ddrescue -d /dev/sda backup.img BACKUP.log
```

(NOTE: the logfile aka mapping file is important in case the backup process is interrupted and enables ddrescue to restart / continue the process from interruption point)

5.) Once finished, create a new vdi, install a minimal operating system (will be overwritten).

6.) in vbox manager add the bootable iso disk to the new vdi and via the disks utility verify that the new vdi's /dev/sda is NOT MOUNTED

7.) install guest additions and ddrescue again, then run:

```
$sudo su
#ddrescue -f /dev/sda backup.img RESTORE.log
```

(NOTE: the logfile aka mapping file is important in case the RESTORE process is interrupted and enables ddrescue to restart / continue the process from interruption point)

8.) Once it finishes you now have a perfect back up of the corrupted vdi, but you are NOT quite done if you use the vdi as a server. In this scenario, when you boot the new vdi, the machine will "fail to raise" Network Interfaces.  This happens because the host has given the guest a new network interface that doesn't match the network interface from the corrupted vdi.  Simply open a rescue shell and run

```
#ifconfig -a
```

This will identify the new network interface name.  Then edit the network interfaces name config for your machine... (debian 10: ex, "eth0")

```
#nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

After you have added the correct network interface name run:

```
#ifconfig "eth0" down && ifnfig "eth0" up
```

Then reboot..  Your done.. back to work! :-)

My reference:
https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Important-advice
https://manpages.debian.org/buster/gddrescue/ddrescue.1.en.html
https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/
https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/758594/no-networking-failed-to-bring-up-eth0